# 'Apply' Oomph preferences to existing workspace

Tags: eclipse, user-preferences, oomph

I've only recently found Oomph for Eclipse (sounded like an amazing feature if I could get it to work), and am having difficulties getting set up. I'm using Eclipse for Java 4.6.0 (Neon).

I have two workspaces that I switch between, one of which has the settings which I'd like across both of the workspaces (initially, after both are set up I'd like any relevant changes to reflect to any other workspaces). I've run the "initialise preferences pages" wizzard (the one with the lightbulb), I've got no idea what to do next as I can't find a tutorial or documentation.

Can anyone offer any help as to what to do next?